# jackson: Object with array invalid json form

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have this code

spring-context.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
```

JsonResponse.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.globe.egg.ggrocery.item.model;

/**
 *
 * @author Farhan Sharief
 */
public class JsonResponse {
private int status;
private Object body;

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Object getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(Object body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public static JsonResponse createResponse(int status, Object body) {
    JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();
    response.setStatus(status);
    response.setBody(body);
    return response;
}
}
```

and my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list",
method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse getCategories() {
    return JsonResponse.createResponse(SUCCESS.getStatus(), categoryService.getCategories()); //returns a List<Category>
}
```

I'm expecting

```
{
"status": 200,
"body": [
    {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "categoryName": "basket",
        "subCategory": "NONE",
        "version": 1
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "categoryName": "Cosmetics",
        "subCategory": "NONE",
        "version": 1
    }
]
}
```

but i'm getting

```
{
    status: 200
    body: [2]
        0:  {
            categoryId: 1
            categoryName: "basket"
            subCategory: "NONE"
            version: 1
            }
        1:  {
            categoryId: 2
            categoryName: "Cosmetics"
            subCategory: "NONE"
            version: 1
        }

}
```

my problem is that the json has no double quotes and structure of the body is not valid. It has [2] in it.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it's because of the view of my advanced rest client.